# Append string in another string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string `a="<tr>i'm working in C#<tr/> abcdefghjiklmnopqr ii oo yy uu hh gg rr"`, and `b="<td>Finish</td></tr>"`. I need string `a` as

```
  a="<tr>i'm working in C#<tr/> <td>Finish</td></tr> abcdefghjiklmnopqr ii oo yy uu hh gg rr".
```

---

How do we append string in string like above? I asked a same question earlier which was wrong. 
Here will have to find for first ">" character and append b in a.

Comment: _"have to find for first > and append b"_ But your desired result appended b at `<tr/> ` so after the second `>`. Apart from that, use `HtmlAgilityPack` to parse or create html dynamically.

Comment: Use indexOf() and insert() methods (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx).

Comment: "insert", not "append".

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;        
while(i < a.Length && (i=a.IndexOf("/>",i)) != -1){
   a = a.Insert(i+2,b);
   i += b.Length;
}
```

Comment: This just mimics `a.Replace("/>", "/>" + b)`. Why is this being done manually?

Comment: @MikePrecup I miss the while loop, in fact this question is so trivial

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do this with indexOf and substrings

```
var a="<tr>i'm working in C#<tr/>abcdefghjiklmnopqr ii oo yy uu hh gg rr";
var b="<td>Finish</td></tr>";

var insertPoint = a.IndexOf("<tr/>")+5;
var c = a.Substring(0,insertPoint) + b + a.Substring(insertPoint);
```

But really if you're trying to do html generation with string concatenation, this will be a nightmare. Try using Razor, or any other templating language.

Answer (score 0):

use insert to append a string at a specific location.

```
String findText = @"<tr/>";
String a = @"<tr>i'm working in C#<tr/> abcdefghjiklmnopqr ii oo yy uu hh gg rr";
String b = @"<td>Finish</td></tr>";
int appendLocation = a.IndexOf(findText) + findText.Length;
String c = a.Insert(appendLocation, b);
MessageBox.Show(c);
```